# How to loop through arrays inside object

Tags: php

I'm very much a beginner so please bear with me.
I am trying to display a JSON response in a table.
I have retrieved the JSON data ok but the structure is a bit complex for me to traverse to get the data I want to display.

It is a school timetable so the format I am going for is below:

```
Session        | Monday        | Tuesday       | Wednesday
-----------------------------------------------------------
Home Room      | 2HRS - JS1.6  | 2HRS - JS1.6  | ....
08:30 - 08:45  | Homeroom      | Homeroom      | ....
               | Ms Jones      | Ms Jones      | ....
               |               |               | 
Period 1       | 2ENS - JS1.6  | 2ENS - JS1.6  | ....
08:45 - 09:35  | English       | English       | ....
               | Ms Jones      | Ms Jones      | ....
```

First thing I am trying to do is loop through the rooms and display them in a table.

This is the beginning of my JSON response:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "description": "Home Room",
        "from_time": "08:30",
        "to_time": "08:45",
        "timetable": {
            "1": {
                "DayNumber": "1",
                "ClassCode": "2HRS",
                "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:30",
                "EndTime": "08:45"
            },
            "2": {
                "DayNumber": "2",
                "ClassCode": "2HRS",
                "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:30",
                "EndTime": "08:45"
            },
            "3": {
                "DayNumber": "3",
                "ClassCode": "2HRS",
                "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:30",
                "EndTime": "08:45"
            },
            "4": {
                "DayNumber": "4",
                "ClassCode": "2HRS",
                "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:30",
                "EndTime": "08:45"
            },
            "5": {
                "DayNumber": "5",
                "ClassCode": "2HRS",
                "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:30",
                "EndTime": "08:45"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "description": "Period 1",
        "from_time": "08:45",
        "to_time": "09:35",
        "timetable": {
            "1": {
                "DayNumber": "1",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:45",
                "EndTime": "09:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "DayNumber": "2",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:45",
                "EndTime": "09:35"
            },
            "3": {
                "DayNumber": "3",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:45",
                "EndTime": "09:35"
            },
            "4": {
                "DayNumber": "4",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:45",
                "EndTime": "09:35"
            },
            "5": {
                "DayNumber": "5",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "08:45",
                "EndTime": "09:35"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Here is some of my code.

```
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);       
$rooms = $response['data']['0']['timetable'];

?>
<?php foreach ($rooms['1'] as $v) { ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td class="first"><?php echo $v;} ?></td>
</tr>
```

This loops through the "1" array and displays the following data on each row.
I just can't seem to navigate far enough down the structure to access to room.

```
1
2HRS
Homeroom
JS.1.6
Yasemin Sali
Ms
Sali
08:30
08:45
```

I may be totally off track here so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

***************** EDIT **********************************

```
Session                    | Monday                      | Tuesday |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
"description"              | "ClassCode" - "Room"        | ....    | 
"from_time" - "to_time" or | "ClassDescription"          | ....    | 
"StartTime" - "EndTime"    | "StaffTitle" "StaffSurname" | ....    | 
---------------------------|-----------------------------|---------| 
"description"              | "ClassCode" - "Room"        | ....    | 
"from_time" - "to_time"    | "ClassDescription"          | ....    | 
"StartTime" - "EndTime"    | "StaffTitle" "StaffSurname" | ....    | 
                           | (if timetable #A exists then|         |
                           |  add below)                 |         |
                           |     -------------------     |         |
                           | "ClassCode" - "Room"        |         |
                           | "ClassDescription"          |         |
                           | "StaffTitle" "StaffSurname" |         |
---------------------------|-----------------------------|---------|
```

******************* EDIT 2***********************************

```
    {
        "description": "Recess",
        "from_time": "10:25",
        "to_time": "10:45",
        "timetable": {
            "1": [],
            "2": [],
            "3": [],
            "4": [],
            "5": []
        }
    },
```

****************** EDIT 3 ******************************************

```
{
        "description": "Period 3",
        "from_time": "10:45",
        "to_time": "11:35",
        "timetable": {
            "1": {
                "DayNumber": "1",
                "ClassCode": "2ENS",
                "ClassDescription": "English",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "10:45",
                "EndTime": "11:35"
            },
            "2": {
                "DayNumber": "2",
                "ClassCode": "2ARS",
                "ClassDescription": "Art",
                "Room": "AR.1.10",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Betty Smith",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Smith",
                "StartTime": "10:45",
                "EndTime": "11:35"
            },
            "3": {
                "DayNumber": "3",
                "ClassCode": "2PES",
                "ClassDescription": "Physical Education",
                "Room": "SP.1.1",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Anne Doe",
                "StaffTitle": "Mrs",
                "StaffSurname": "Doe",
                "StartTime": "10:45",
                "EndTime": "11:35"
            },
            "4": {
                "DayNumber": "4",
                "ClassCode": "2MAS",
                "ClassDescription": "Mathematics",
                "Room": "JS.1.6",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "10:45",
                "EndTime": "11:35"
            },
            "5": {
                "DayNumber": "5",
                "ClassCode": "2LBS",
                "ClassDescription": "Library",
                "Room": "",
                "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
                "StaffTitle": "Ms",
                "StaffSurname": "Jones",
                "StartTime": "10:45",
                "EndTime": "11:35"
            },
            "5A": [
                {
                    "DayNumber": "5",
                    "ClassCode": "2LBS2",
                    "ClassDescription": "Library",
                    "Room": "RC.1.2",
                    "StaffNameExternal": "Rebecca Williams",
                    "StaffTitle": "Mrs",
                    "StaffSurname": "Gallagher",
                    "StartTime": "10:45",
                    "EndTime": "11:35"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi, can you please give us an example of how you'd like the end result to be? I don't mean values but keys.

Comment: Hi Keith. I have updated the table with keys rather than values. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Session</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($response['data'] as $data): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $data['description']; ?><br/>
                    <?php echo $data['from_time'] . ' - ' . $data['to_time']; ?>
                </td>
                <?php foreach ($data['timetable'] as $desc): ?>
                    <?php if ($data['description'] != "Recess"): ?>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $desc['ClassCode'] . ' - ' . $desc['Room']; ?><br/>
                            <?php echo $desc['ClassDescription']; ?><br/>
                            <?php echo $desc['StaffTitle'] . ' - ' . $desc['StaffSurname']; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code is assuming that the json value has complete timetable from Monday to Friday and the day is sort ascending.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks for that David. There is a couple of issues, however, and it's totally my fault because I didn't include the full JSON response.

Comment: are there any problems that you encountered?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally published my comment. I have added a second edit to my post for the first issue. After Period 2, there is "Recess" which does not contain the same keys/values as the other Periods.

Comment: The other issue is that some days have an extra period. See Edit 3. Period 3 has a "Day 5A". This is because students will have different subjects on alternating weeks.

Comment: I have updated the table in EDIT 1 to reflect the format to include "Day 5A" if it exists. I hope it makes sense

Comment: hmmm, why 5A has an array inside where the other hasn't?

Comment: Some periods on some days have alternate the subject. So, for example, one week that period will be Science, then the following week that period will be Library.

Comment: I get it. But, take a look at this `"5A": [{...}]`. Do you really intent to be this way? The other is like this `"5":{...}`

Comment: Oh right. I see. This data is coming from an API developed by a developer that has now left the school so I can't answer that question unfortunately. Can it be done using this format?

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to use the API we have, but perhaps I should query our database directly instead if that will be easier.

Comment: i will try to modify my answer based on current question

Comment: it turns out to be a mess when i am trying to edit my answer. i guess you should change the json format to make it easier.

Comment: I think that will prove to be too great a challenge for me. I may have to look at querying the database directly instead. Thanks so much for all your help though. I've learned heaps from your code.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you JSON validates and simplify it too.

```
{
"data": [{
    "description": "Home Room",
    "from_time": "08:30",
    "to_time": "08:45",
    "timetable": [
        {
            "DayNumber": "1",
            "ClassCode": "2HRS",
            "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
            "Room": "JS.1.6",
            "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
            "StaffTitle": "Ms",
            "StaffSurname": "Jones",
            "StartTime": "08:30",
            "EndTime": "08:45"
        },
        {
            "DayNumber": "2",
            "ClassCode": "2HRS",
            "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
            "Room": "JS.1.6",
            "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
            "StaffTitle": "Ms",
            "StaffSurname": "Jones",
            "StartTime": "08:30",
            "EndTime": "08:45"
        },
        {
            "DayNumber": "3",
            "ClassCode": "2HRS",
            "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
            "Room": "JS.1.6",
            "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
            "StaffTitle": "Ms",
            "StaffSurname": "Jones",
            "StartTime": "08:30",
            "EndTime": "08:45"
        },
        {
            "DayNumber": "4",
            "ClassCode": "2HRS",
            "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
            "Room": "JS.1.6",
            "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
            "StaffTitle": "Ms",
            "StaffSurname": "Jones",
            "StartTime": "08:30",
            "EndTime": "08:45"
        },
        {
            "DayNumber": "5",
            "ClassCode": "2HRS",
            "ClassDescription": "Homeroom",
            "Room": "JS.1.6",
            "StaffNameExternal": "Sally Jones",
            "StaffTitle": "Ms",
            "StaffSurname": "Jones",
            "StartTime": "08:30",
            "EndTime": "09:35"
        }
    ]
}]
}
```

Then you can do something like this

```
<?php
$get_data = file_get_contents('inf.json');

$response = json_decode($get_data, true);       
$rooms = $response['data']['0']['timetable'];
?>
<?php foreach ($rooms as $v) { 
    echo $v['DayNumber'];
    echo " ";
    echo $v['ClassCode'];
    echo " ";
    echo $v['ClassDescription'];
    echo $v['Room'];
    echo " ";
    echo $v['StaffNameExternal'];
    echo " ";
    echo $v['StaffTitle'];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you simply echo the value, not store the value in table.